# Unable to install SSL in Apache

Tags: apache, ubuntu, tomcat, ssl, server

My server is Ubuntu and I am running `Apache2`. I am using apache to point to my web app loaded in `tomcat`. Below is my `000-default.conf` file.

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # Servers to proxy the connection, or;
    # List of application servers:
    # Usage:
    # ProxyPass / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
    # ProxyPassReverse / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
    # Example:
    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8080/

    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    SSL Engine On

    # Set the path to SSL certificate
    # Usage: SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/STAR_myglukose_com.crt

    # Servers to proxy the connection, or;
    # List of application servers:
    # Usage:
    # ProxyPass / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
    # ProxyPassReverse / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
    # Example:
    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8080/

    # Or, balance the load:
    # ProxyPass / balancer://balancer_cluster_name

</VirtualHost>
```

My pointing to Tomcat is fine but the issue is with SSL. After creating the virtual host for 443, I am unable to restart the apache. I am getting an error. It asks me to refer `journalct1 -xe`. This file is as below.

```
Aug 01 16:45:20 ip-172-31-5-246 apache2[27556]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Aug 01 16:45:20 ip-172-31-5-246 apache2[27556]:  *
Aug 01 16:45:20 ip-172-31-5-246 apache2[27556]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Aug 01 16:45:20 ip-172-31-5-246 apache2[27556]: Output of config test was:
Aug 01 16:45:20 ip-172-31-5-246 apache2[27556]: [Tue Aug 01 16:45:20.638254 2017] [proxy_html:notice] [pid 27567] AH01425: I18n support in mod_proxy_html requires mod_xml2enc. Without it, non-ASCII characters in proxied pages are likely to display incorrectly. it, n
Aug 01 16:45:20 ip-172-31-5-246 apache2[27556]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 19 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:
Aug 01 16:45:20 ip-172-31-5-246 apache2[27556]: Invalid command 'SSL', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Aug 01 16:45:20 ip-172-31-5-246 apache2[27556]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Aug 01 16:45:20 ip-172-31-5-246 apache2[27556]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Aug 01 16:45:20 ip-172-31-5-246 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 01 16:45:20 ip-172-31-5-246 sudo[27550]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Aug 01 16:45:20 ip-172-31-5-246 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
```

I tried various ways to settle this up, including writing the `SSL Engine` as `SSLEngine`, executing `sudo a2enmod ssl`, etc but the same error comes in.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message clearly points out the problem:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 19 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:
Invalid command 'SSL', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

To fix the problem look at the specific line:

```
SSL Engine On
```

and fix it by removing the space between SSL and Engine:

```
SSLEngine On
```

Comment: Yes, I fixed it before as mentioned in my question but didn't work as expected. Anyway it suddenly started working